# Are there any verses which pray for the birth of daughter in Vedas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, rig-veda, women, atharva-veda

> Prajāpati, Anumati, Sinivāli have ordered it. Elsewhere may he effect
>   the birth of maids, but here prepare a boy.-Atharva Veda 6.11.3

There are especial hymns and verses in Vedas which pray for the birth of a son like Atharva Veda  3.23.

> Be not divided; dwell ye here; reach the full time of human    life.
>   With sons and grandsons sport and play, rejoicing in your happy
>   home, -Atharva Veda 14.1.22;
>
> I cook the offering, I present oblation: only my wife attends the holy service.   A youthful world, a son hath been begotten. Begin a life that    brings success and triumph. -Atharva Veda 12.3.47
>
> Unmarried men desire to wed; bountiful givers wish for sons. Together may we dwell with strength unscathed for high prosperity. --Atharva Veda 14.2.72
>
> Wise, teaching, following the thought of Order, the sonless gained a grandson from his daughter. Fain, as a sire, to see his child
>   prolific, he sped to meet her with an eager spirit. --Rig Veda 3.31.1

Above verses only emphasise on son over daughter.  Are there any verses which pray for daughters too?

Comment: because lineage (gotra) is continued through son, not daughter. only sons *can* perform tarpana/shraddha for pitrus. whether they will do it or not nowadays is a different matter.. but there is also great reward for begetting a daughter, because if you do kanya-daan to a valid brahmachari who learned vedas, then you go to brahma-loka. you won't go to brahma loka if you arrange marriage of your son.

Comment: the mantra - 'kanya kanaka sampanna.. brahma loka jigeeshaya' - not sure which sutras have this

Comment: @Ajay Yes. Kanya Danam takes parents to Brahma Loka, highest loka as per Vedas. In Andhra, certain castes adopt maidens (if they don't have daughters) at time of marriage, to get benefit of Kanya Daanam.

Comment: @ram these claims are not true.

Comment: Add a sentence saying that a particular article makes that claim. There are some verses in Grihya sutras for daughters.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi these claims are true.

Comment: @ram i will prove with help of references.

Comment: Gandhari: But I should be very happy if a daughter were born of me over and above these hundred sons and junior to them all. My husband then may attain to those worlds that the possession of a daughter's sons conferreth. ~http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01117.htm

Comment: @YDS - excellent find

Comment: @ram "because lineage (gotra) is continued through son," lineage is only continued via a man AND a woman.

Comment: @Wikash_, no it's not. if you have a daughter and give her away in marriage, her gotra changes to that of her husband

Comment: @ram do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @Wikash_, the entire vedic tradition in India. anyone who knows their gotra will tell you it's derived from their father. when choosing horscopes, it is the first thing to look at to prevent sagotra marriages

Comment: @ram tradition is not equal to religion. People can make up anything. It is the scriptures which describe hindiusm not tradition.

Comment: @Wikash_, the tradition is according to scriptures. all marriage rituals are according to scriptures.

Comment: @ram can you point to a specific verse in the scriptures?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not that the Vedas only praise the birth of a male child alone. There are instances where female progeny is also praised. Further, it is important to know that the word "putra" does not necessarily mean only male child but could mean child in general. Similarly in many places word "man" does not only indicate men but all of the mankind including men and women.

> O Brahman, let there be born in the kingdom the Brahman illustrious
>   for religious knowledge; let there be born the Râjanya, heroic,
>   skilled archer, piercing with shafts, mighty warrior; the cow giving
>   abundant milk; the ox good at carrying; the swift courser; the
>   **industrious woman**. May Parjanya send rain according to our desire; may
>   our fruit-bearing plants ripen; may acquisition and preservation of
>   property be secured to us. (**Shukla Yajurveda 22.22**)
>
> My Sons are slayers of the foe, **my Daughter is a ruling Queen**:  I am
>   victorious: o’er my Lord my song of triumph is supreme. **Rigveda
>   10.159.3**
>
> With sons and **daughters** by their side they reach their full extent of
>   life, Both decked with ornaments of gold. **R.V 8.31.8**
>
> With many a son, father of **many daughters**, He clangs and clashes as he
>   goes to battle. Slung on the back, pouring his brood, the Quiver
>   vanquishes all opposing bands and armies. **R.V 6.75.5**

Some scholars have attempted to prove the daughter as an
unwelcome member of the family but it’s absolutely against the tenets
of the Vedas which suggest quite the opposite to these claims. In
subsequent ages women have been denied the privilege of Upanayana too
which is not in accordance with the vedic injunctions. See the
following quotes from the gRhya sUtras: (Which are the practical manuals for conducting the Vedic rites and rituals)

Parents desirous of obtaining a **daughter perform the KAmya ShrAddha** on
the second day of the moon (**Gobhila ParishiSTa ShrAddha Kalpa**
[Calcutta ed.p.186] ## PAraskara GRhya Sutra 1.21 )

When a husband is **desirous of having a daughter**, he should touch all
the fingers of his wife except her thumb during the marriage ceremony.
**(AshvalAyana GRhya SUtra 2:125, Apastamba GRhya SUtra
यदि कामयेत स्त्रीरेव जनयेयमित्यङ्गुलिरेव गृह्णीयात् 6:12)**

**Wishing for a daughte**r, the husband shows the bride the Dhruva and
other constellations ( **kAthaka Grhya Sutra commentary** जीवन्तीं
कन्यामिच्छन् ध्रुवादिकं दर्शयेत् 2 :1-2 )

So it is very obvious to a discerning person that the girl child was
never disliked or unwelcome in the household. In fact special prayers
and propitiations were conducted to have a girl in the family!

Comment: How does this answer the question: "Are there any verses which pray for daughters?" E.g., [AV 6.11](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av06011.htm) ("An epithalamian charm to ensure the birth of a boy") is clearly praying for male offspring. Are you saying it's a translation error so same prayer works for girl child?

Comment: @sv. I have cited verses which pray/wish/glorify the birth of a female child !! what is the confusion ?

Comment: 'glorify the birth of a female' - yes, I see some in your answer, but isn't OP asking for specific verses similar to AV 6.11? Maybe you can edit your answer and move such verses to the beginning?

Comment: @sv. Let the OP talk himself there is no need of proxies. Look at the grihya sutra references for more clear prayer for a specific ritual like kaamya shraddha.

Comment: Very nice answer thanks for sharing these verses!

Answer (score 12):

There is a verse in  **Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 6.4.17** , Which says -

> **अथ य इच्छेद्दुहिता मे पण्डिता जायेत , सर्वमायु-रियादिति,** 
>  **तिलौदनं**
>   **पाचयित्वा सर्पिम्षन्तमश्रीयाताम् ; इश्वरौ जनयितवै ||१७||**
>
> **He who wishes that daughter to be born to him who would be a scholar**
>   **and attain a full term of life , should have rice cooked with sesamum.**

Now its clear from above verses that people from Vedic period   also wish a daughter child to be born to them. And this hymn shows the way to  those who
Want their daughters to become a scholar and live a long life .

There is no instance in Rug-Veda  where the birth of a girl  child was considered inferior.

It indicates that the position of a girl in Rig Vedic times was not  considered a low. 
**Very few number of verses regarding this matter  perhaps indicative  that society  in need  of larger number of male warriors to ensure its survival.**

---

[image]

Comment: I dont want to sound rude, but out of pure interest: is this verse to be taken literally?

Comment: My question now is the same Upanishad ask to beat women just few verses before.

Comment: @downrep_nation - Well its personal view.But i think its sure not a spell or remedy kind of verse , so it should be taken in positive way , that society needs Boys as well as girls both to flourish.

Comment: @Ajay - I appreciate your  inquiry. But i think you should ask a separate question. Then both will be separate questions , because that  one is concerning  about women i.e. after the stage of birth  of girl child. And current one is of asking / praying for  a girl child.

Comment: @Ajay - That beating is mild one  and symbolic just for cursing purpose.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar yes. Your explanation is correct. But I have seen the same question which you requested me to ask separately in this website already without answer.

Comment: @Ajay - Yes , I remember that , but i think that's  the right way.  instead of answering questions in comments sections i would suggest users to ask separate question , this way it will reach to large no. of audience. its a little difficult to answer in this section also.

Comment: Jeevatma flows from food only. See Chandogya Upanishad. This hymn actually works, not merely be taken literally.

Comment: @Aghori - yes , agree with your view.

Comment: Nice find once again @SwiftPushkar

Answer (score 1):

**Atharvaveda 12.3.47**

> I cook the offering, I present oblation: only my wife attends the holy
>   service. A youthful world, **a son hath been begotten**. Begin a life that
>   brings success and triumph.

Clearly. the term used in past tense. It does not refer to a thing that is going to happen.So, this cannot be considered as prayer.

**Atharvaveda 14.2.72**

> “Unmarried men desire to have a wife , married men desire for an
>   offspring (child of any gender)

**There is no prayer for son here.**

**Atharva Veda 3.23**

Read the fourth line first:

> With that auspicious general flow wherewith **the bulls propagate**    their
>   kind,   Do thou obtain thyself a son: **be thou a fruitful! mother-cow.**

Does this look like getting a male child from cow and bull?? Looks wired? Not at all. The male animal here is the spiritual insight reflecting the spiritual eye concept. This is not at all or humans. This is a metaphor.