# About Girl child - What does Vedas and Shastras say in Sanatana Dharma.?

Tags: scripture, vedas, advaita, dharma-shastras, reference

Just curious to know what do Vedas or Shastras say about a girl child? Like from when it's born to her journey of life.

Can someone give some references.?

Comment: Vedas will not say about these. It is the [dharma shastra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma%C5%9B%C4%81stra) that is common for all that will prescribe life-stage events called 'samskaras' for child of any gender. For girl child, the notable one starts with her attaining `puberty`, the earlier stage events like anna prasana, karna chood being all same like boy child. The family may be following a specific 'kalpa sutra', which needs to be known and followed. Example kalpa sutras are bodhayana, vaikhanasa , apastambha, etc

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran, thank you for your comment. Could you throw some more light on this topic?

Comment: Let me know what kind of more info you are looking for?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran, usually, the birth of a girl child is frowned upon? Why is that so? I've also heard that a few people say that only a male has the right to do the final rites of a father or mother or any relative for that matter. Is it because of this the birth of a girl is frowned upon? Also, people say that if a married person does not give birth to a son, then he has sinned. Only sinners give birth to female children as he does not have any direct male to do his final rites once he passes away. Can u throw some light on the above points which made me ask the above question?

Comment: I think it's duplicate of this question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18910/647

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, the link that you suggested does not contain any answers that help to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

In Vedas and shastras there are some rituals which are done for birth of a girl child.

> **Yajur Veda 22.22** “O Brahman, may here be born in the kingdom, the Brahmin illustrious for poetic knowledge; let there be born the Rajanya, heroic, skilled archer, piercing with shafts, mighty warrior; the cow giving abundant milk; the ox good at carrying; the swift courser; the industrious woman. May Parjanya send rain according to our desire; may our fruit-bearing plants ripen; may acquisition and preservation of property be secured to us.”

> **Asvalayana Grihya Sutra 1.2.1-5** “Now various indeed are the customs of the (different) countries and the customs of the (different) villages: those one should observe at the wedding. What, however, is commonly accepted, that we shall state. Having placed to the west of the fire a mill-stone, to the north-east (of the fire) a water-pot, he should sacrifice, while she takes hold of him. Standing, with his face turned to the west, while she is sitting and turns her face to the east, he should with (the formula), ‘I seize thy hand for the sake of happiness seize her thumb if he desires that only male children may be born to him; Her other fingers, **(if he is) desirous of female (children); The hand on the hair-side together with the thumb, if desirous of both male and female children.“**

> **Agni Purana 325. 20-22a** “By this worship, a person desirous of getting a daughter would get a daughter, a person not having a son would get a son, an unfortunate woman would get fortune….”

As per Mahabharata, a girl child is equal to a boy.

> **Anushasan Parva 13.47.26** “The daughter, O king, has been ordained in the scriptures to be equal to the son.”